# fcntl's F_GETLK not returning lock details

Tags: c, linux, unix, locking, fcntl

I am taking read lock using fcntl's F_SETLKW then trying read the same lock from same process using fcntl's F_GETLK. But result is not appropriate. Below is sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;
    struct flock fl;

    if ( (fd = open("lockfile", O_RDWR)) == -1 ) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&fl, 0, sizeof(struct flock));
    fl.l_type   = F_RDLCK;  // Read lock
    fl.l_start  = 10;       // lock on offset 2
    fl.l_len    = 1;        // lock length
    fl.l_whence = 0;        // lock value from start

    if ( fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1 )
    {
        perror("fcntl:SETLK");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Read Lock successfull\n");

    if ( fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &fl) == -1 )
    {
        perror("fcntl:GETLK");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d\n", F_RDLCK, F_WRLCK, F_UNLCK);
    printf("Lock Type   : %d\n", fl.l_type);
    printf("Lock pid    : %d\n", fl.l_pid);
    printf("Lock offset : %d\n", fl.l_start);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Read Lock successfull
0 1 2
Lock Type   : 2
Lock pid    : 0
Lock offset : 10
```

It returning lock type as 2 (F_UNLCK) and it not returning pid of the process which took the lock.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  suggest always enabling all the warnings when compiling then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Answer (score 1):

F_GETLCK will change the fl.l_type to F_UNLCK if there is no lock that prevent others being created. Since your fl is F_RDLCK, then after called fcntl() F_GETLCK won't get any error and change the lock type to F_UNLCK

Comment: but i checked same code for F_WRLCK it also return same result as about, and not give pid.

Comment: basically you wont get any error because you are running in the same process, so it will replace the current lock to the new lock, here is some reference about locking
[link](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=kCTMFpEcIOwC&pg=PA488&lpg=PA488&dq=read+lock+and+write+lock+in+same+process&source=bl&ots=zvHBRRZvpD&sig=0dduWqgvuis6cqWBvAO5EQf-znM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBWoVChMI_7yLjfzmyAIVC4yUCh0iXATI#v=onepage&q=read%20lock%20and%20write%20lock%20in%20same%20process&f=false) in page 487 has the detail, i am currently learning this so hopefully i didnt get it wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for your link. I took F_WRLCK then i am reading using F_GETLK then it has to return F_WRLCK  instead it returning F_UNLCK. So as per the book's author F_UNLCK will be set if no lock exist. But i took lock initially. Pls clarify this